# Having difficulty in understanding Akka-http sample tutorial

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I don't have any experience with backend, I want to make a few rest endpoints using akka-http.
Every tutorial I see on the internet has a different skeleton/structure and different names for things.

I know the business logic I want to implement but I have spent a lot of time figuring out where to put it and how the project structure should look like but to no avail.

Some projects/tutorials are explicitly using actors others aren't. Repository, Service confusing interchangeable names. Each project/tutorial has totally different project/code structure.

Even The [basic tutorial](https://github.com/akka/akka-http-quickstart-scala.g8/tree/10.1.x/src/main/g8/src/main/scala/%24package%24) provided by light bend itself is very different from others. As in the **actormaterializer** is no where to be found even tho akka-stream is a dependency, and uses **Command** and **ActionRef** other tutorials are totally different.

How good is the tutorial example provided by lightbend? If its good I can copy that pattern.

Also, could someone explain a bit the basics, the best practices and how to structure code and where does the logic goes?

sbt file for the versions.

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      organization    := "com.example",
      scalaVersion    := "2.13.1"
    )),
    name := "My Akka HTTP Project",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http"                % akkaHttpVersion,
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json"     % akkaHttpVersion,
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed"         % akkaVersion,
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream"              % akkaVersion,
      "ch.qos.logback"    % "logback-classic"           % "1.2.3",

      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-testkit"        % akkaHttpVersion % Test,
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-testkit-typed" % akkaVersion     % Test,
      "org.scalatest"     %% "scalatest"                % "3.0.8"         % Test
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

The [tutorial](https://github.com/akka/akka-http-quickstart-scala.g8/tree/10.1.x/src/main/g8/src/main/scala/%24package%24) you linked is a good example with up-to-date best practice. However, this might not be the best fit if you simply want to build a web application or a simple REST API. Here are why.

The reason why you find it confusing is that Akka is NOT an HTTP framework. Akka starts with akka-actor, which implements the [actor model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) with Scala and believes this is a good way atop of which to build distributed systems. akka-http is just a module that builds on top of akka-actor (as almost every other module does) that provides some goodies for users to build a web application while integrating very well with Akka ecosystem.

That being said, if bootstrapping a web application or a REST API fast-and-easy is what you're looking for, akka-http may not be the best choice. Lightbend does provide [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/), which, again, builds atop of akka-actor, but hides the complexity.

Comment: I'd also add Lagom, which is a sort of halfway house between full-on Akka and Play (it's basically Play (which already includes Akka HTTP and thus Akka Streams and Akka Actors) plus Akka Cluster, Akka Cluster Sharding and Akka Persistence).